# How do I pass a variable from a shell script to my .muttrc?

Tags: bash, shell-script, mutt

I'd like `mutt` (`mutt-kz`, actually -- I'd love to migrate to `neomutt` but that's a bigger project) to get my SMTP password from `pass` so I don't have to keep it stored in cleartext in my config file, but I'm not sure how to properly pass the password into my `.muttrc`.

This is what I have in `.muttrc`:

```
source ~/.mutt/pass.sh|
set smtp_pass = $my_pass
```

And then `.mutt/pass.sh` contains:

```
#! /bin/bash
my_pass=$(pass Example/user)
```

If I add `echo ${my_pass}` to `pass.sh` and run it from the command line, it does echo my password.

When I launch `mutt-kz` I'm prompted to unlock my `pass` gpg key, so something is working, but when I try to send mail from Mutt it asks for my SMTP password and fails if I don't provide it the message isn't sent: ("SASL authentication failed")

So ... how do I correctly pass the variable from my shell script to my `.muttrc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program `~/.mutt/pass.sh` must produce output that looks like

```
set my_pass = swordfish
```

So it can be something like

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "set my_pass = swordfish"
```

Note that if your password contains certain special characters (`\'"` and whitespace), you'll need to [quote it](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#muttrc-syntax). For example, if your password is in the text file `~/passwords/smtp.txt`, you can use:

```
#!/bin/sh
~/passwords/smtp.txt sed 's/["$`\\]/\\&/g; s/^/set my_pass = "/; s/$/"/'
```

For the password `sword\fish`, this prints `set my_pass="sword\\fish"`.

If you use Gnome-keyring to store your passwords then you can use the `secret-tool` utility to read your password from the keyring. For example, this is what I use for an Office 365 password (with a password that doesn't contain any special character that needs quoting):

```
source 'printf "set imap_pass="; secret-tool lookup action_url https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/login |'
```

Comment: `secret-tool` requires even number of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The other possibility would be use of backtick expansion.
So you should be able to do:

```
my_pass = `pass Example/user`
```

If you migrate to `neomutt` eventually you could also define variable with command line, i.e.

```
my_pass=$(pass Example/user) mutt
```

and then you can use `my_pass` variable as in your example.